# How can I reset the database migration of Entity Framework 4

Tags: entity-framework-4

I'm using ASP MVC 4 and EF 4.
I use the Package Manager Console to run Enable-Migration command.
I then did some changes and run Add-Migration after each of them.
I now want to clear all the small changes and re-create a single migration script.

How can I do that?

Where does EF remember the "last entity state" from which it derive the next Add-Migration script?

Thank you,
Ido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that the Enable-Migration script create the _MigrationHistory table which store the migration already apply to the database.
After I've delete the records in that table and the migration scripts from the Migration directory I've re-run Add-Migration and it create a single migration script.